# Is there a concern by stripping some files off the Google Play services jar file?

Tags: java, android, jar, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Our app is using the Google Play services SDK for GCM push notification, however there is com.google.ads package inside the jar file. Due to this, our app is flagged as advertisement app by some mobile security app. I removed the com.google.ads package from google-play-services.jar and GCM push is still working fine with stripped down jar.

Is there a concern by stripping some files off the Google Play services jar file?  Have you seen the same issue before?  Somehow I could not see any related information about this over internet search.

Comment: Proguard should stripped down all unused classes ...

Comment: thanks, we do use proguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem, as far as nobody tries to load any of those classes.

Think that in java the classes are loaded on demand, as you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader):

> The Java Classloader is a part of the Java Runtime Environment that
>   dynamically loads Java classes into the Java Virtual Machine.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)
>   Usually classes are only loaded on demand. The Java run time system
>   does not need to know about files and file systems because of
>   classloaders.

So the classes existing or supposed to exists, in a jar are not parsed in any fashion, whatever it is inside, it is only a bunch of resources that are meant to may be called by the app. Actually that jar is just a library providing classes that work as a bridge between your app and some other stuff installed in the device, but you only load the classes that you need.

Also, and the consistence of the files inside are not checked as long as the content is not "sealed". As you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/),

> Package Sealing: Packages stored in JAR files can be optionally sealed
>   so that the package can enforce version consistency. Sealing a package
>   within a JAR file means that all classes defined in that package must
>   be found in the same JAR file.

A package could be sealed, but if you already broke the jar, tried it in one device, and it worked, that means that it is not sealed.

So, as far as the classes that you actually need exists, and the version of them is the correct one, nothing else should happen.

Comment: Perhaps, but keep in mind that at the implementation level Android does not utilize a JVM, but rather treats java bytecode as an intermediate compile stage and further translates it to instructions for a different type of machine.  It's more or less source compatible, but obscure corners of VM behavior may or may not be the same.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that is true. Actually the first that i thought is that DVM, or google play services itself, could try to check any further detail. But if it worked in one device, we can say that all the points in the "standard" or known checklist are passed, and we can infer that there is not other specific ones. For sure, this is not documented stuff AFAIK, so i wont say i'm 100% sure about this, but i wont be worried.